A nonexpansive mapping and a pair of sequences
Let $a<b$ be real numbers and let $f:[a, b]\to [a, b]$ be a function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|$ for all $x, y\in [a, b]$. Define the sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ by $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}x_n+\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}\right), \quad y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_n+\frac{1}{2}f\left(\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}\right), \quad \forall n\ge 0,$$ where $x_0, y_0\in [a, b]$ are given. Prove that the sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ are convergent and they have the same limit.
Here are my thoughts on this problem. If we subtract the two equations, we get $$x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n-y_n), \forall n\ge 0.$$
This means that $$x_n-y_n=\frac{1}{2^n}(x_0-y_0), \forall n\ge 0,$$
so we basically reduce our recurrences involving both sequences to a recurrence involving only one of the sequences. Explicitly, we have to study the recurrence
$$y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_n+\frac{1}{2}f\left(y_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(x_0-y_0)\right), \forall n\ge 0.$$
Now if $f$ were a contraction this would be really easy. But here $f$ is only nonexpansive, so I don't really know what to do because if I try to approach this as in the contraction case I quickly get stuck.

I think the following could work: First note that $x \mapsto g(x):=x+f(x)$ is increasing on $[a,b]$, since $x \le y$ implies
$$
f(x)-f(y) \le |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|=y-x ~ \Rightarrow ~ f(x)+x \le f(y)+y.
$$
Now set $z_n:=(x_n+y_n)/2$. Adding the two equations (and division by $2$) yields
$$
z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}z_n + \frac{1}{2}f(z_n) = \frac{1}{2}g(z_n).
$$
Since $g/2$ is increasing the sequence $(z_n)$ is monotone (increasing if $z_0 \le z_1$ and decreasing if $z_0 \ge z_1$). Since $(z_n)$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$ it is also bounded and thus convergent. At this point we know (including your observations) that
$$
x_n-y_n \to 0 ~ (n\to \infty), \quad x_n+y_n \to 2c ~ (n\to \infty)
$$
for some $c \in [a,b]$. Adding these limits yields
$$
2x_n=(x_n-y_n) +(x_n+y_n) \to 2c \quad (n\to \infty),
$$
so $x_n \to c$  and $y_n \to c$ $(n\to \infty)$.
